# How to isolate tiers in xproj

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, csproj, tiers

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and projects that includes ASP.NET Core Web, in others project libraries.

Time ago, its impossible uses a namespace indirectly whithout reference between projects (in csproj). But in xproj its possible access namespace referenced in another project, ex.:

csproj Proj.Web > Proj.Business > Proj.Data
    Proj.Data is NOT accessible in Proj.Web

versus

xproj Proj.Web > Proj.Business > Proj.Data
    Proj.Data is accessible in Proj.Web

Please, how to simulate same behavior, isolating layers between projects in xproj?

Tks